# User write in a subfolder when cant access parent?

Tags: linux, user-accounts, file-permissions

I was wondering, i have a webfolder and have permissions set to 770 with group being www-data. I would like to give access to one folder to a friend so he can edit images, css, etc. I made that folder 770 with group being site_name with www-data and him being in the group. So far so good it sounds like. However when i use the full path to the directory linux says it doesnt exist.

Is there a way i can make it so he doesnt have r/w file on files inside the parent directories and still access the directory i want to give him?

Comment: you already have a perfect answer, but anyway always check the relevant log files which are your friends.. most of the times you can figure out and fix the issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

He needs execution access (+x) on the parent directory. He will not be able to see or modify the contents, just traverse it.

The way to provide it is up to you, use a group if you want, or just give (o+x) if you don't care that other people are able to traverse the parent.

Comment: perfect (7 more to go..)